# Conditional background image in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on a WordPress site, and would like to set a different background image only for one specific page.  Here is the current CSS calling for the image:

```
div#header .box-masthead .title a{
background:transparent url(../images/logo.png) left top no-repeat
```

How can I set it up so that I can use something like logo-2.png as the background image only on one specific page, while keeping logo.png as the background image on all other pages?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress gives every page a `page-id` class that can be found on the body tag. It looks like `page-id-xxx` where xxx is a number. I you find out your page-id then it's easy to change the background for that specific page:

```
body.page-id-10 {
    background-image: url("../images/logo.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below CSS on the basis of WordPress page id -

```
.page-id-PAGEID div#header .box-masthead .title a {
    background:transparent url(../images/logo.png) left top no-repeat;
 }
```

Note: Replace "PAGEID" with page id in WordPress.